# List comprehension return:TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just to give a context of what I was trying to do. 
dataset is from data.world/notgibs 
I created a new list named album and trying to use list comprehension to get the number of album released in 1974. Here is my code:

```
with open ('/Users/Weindependent/Desktop/dataset/albumlist.csv', encoding='cp1252') as case0:
    reader = csv.DictReader(case0) #the file is coded with single-byte coding
    album = []
    for row in reader:
        album.append(row)
print (len(album))
```

I am creating a new list named album_1974
For each album (row) in my album list where the “Year” is 1974, append to a new list named album_1974

```
album_1974 = [row for row in album if row["Year"]=='1974'] 
print ("Number of albums released in 1974:", len(album_1974))
```

The error is: TypeError: string indices must be integers

attempt:
I figured there are some non-integer value in the year column, so I went ahead and define is_valid_year:

```
def is_valid_year(string):
    try:
        year = int(string)
    except:
        return TypeError
    else:
        return year
```

and put it back to my previous script:

```
album_1974 = [row for row in album if is_valid_year(row["Year"]=="1974")] #this is list comprehension 
print ("No of album in 1974 released:",len(album_1974))
```

The error still exits

I then try to use sort function to sort the albums in my list by year, same error occurs: 
My code:

```
album_sort = sorted(album,lambda = x : s["Artist"]
print (Album_sort)
```

same error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Can someone help?

Comment: You need to provide the structure of data set to figure out the problem. Without knowing the data type, it's hard to tell what exactly is causing the problem. Currently it seems that `row` is not some dictionary but a list

Comment: What do you mean by data structure?

Comment: Structure means if it's a list of lists, list of dictionaries, dictionary containing lists, dictionary containing dictionaries etc.. If `row=[1,2,3,4]` then `row["Year"]` would fail. If `row={"Year": '1974'}`, then  `row["Year"]` would work. But since we don't know how  `album` looks like, we don't know what is `row` and so we don't know if `row["Year"]` exists or not

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This is how album  look like:[OrderedDict([('Number', '1'), ('Year', '1967'), ('Album', "Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band"), ('Artist', 'The Beatles'), ('Genre', 'Rock'), ('Subgenre', 'Rock & Roll, Psychedelic Rock')]

Comment: Is your code really exactly like you posted it, with both parts just one after another (not in functions or whatever), and is your data sample what you get if you print it just before trying to build `album_1974`?

Comment: yes. it is. It is very strange cuz I open another Jyupter notebook and it works now... and I re-run same code, the error appears again....

Comment: Is the closing parenthesis) in the first line of your last example really _after_ the comparison? Apart from that "TypeError: string indices must be integers" means you are using ``container[item]`` _on_ a string, with an ``item`` other than an ``int``.

Comment: ummm I dont really get it.

Comment: Please do not comment comments asking for additional information or clarification: edit your post. `This is how album look like:[OrderedDict(` should go right into your question. `figured there are some non-integer value in the year column` figuring there are non-dict values in `album`, in particular, at least on string.

Comment: I did. I have upatded my question. The issue still exits